# C array of pointers, casting and / or memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory, casting

I don't understand why these pointer values seem to be correct, but the values I am trying to get out of them are not.  (I studied C a long time ago, and I am recently trying to get back into it for fun).

Here is a working example of the problem I am facing, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong - am I casting the pointers incorrectly, not correctly managing memory, or something else.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Q_STACK_MAX 100

typedef struct
{
    void* value[Q_STACK_MAX];
    int top;
} Stack;


void push(Stack* S, void* val)
{
    S->value[S->top] = val; 
    (S->top)++;
}

void* pop(Stack* S)
{
    (S->top)--;
    return (S->value[S->top]);
}

void init(Stack* S)
{
    S->top = 0;
}

int full(Stack* S)
{
    return (S->top >= Q_STACK_MAX);
}


void recursive_dir(char* dir, char* search, Stack* S)
{
    DIR* dp;
    struct dirent* entry;
    struct stat statbuf;
    if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }

    chdir(dir);
    while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        lstat(entry->d_name, &statbuf);

        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            if(strcmp(".", entry->d_name) == 0 ||
                strcmp("..", entry->d_name) == 0)
                    continue;

            recursive_dir(entry->d_name, search, S);
        } else {
            if( strstr(entry->d_name, search) != NULL ) {
                if(!full(S)) push(S, (void *)entry);

                printf("%p\n", entry);
                printf("%s [%x]\n", entry->d_name, entry->d_ino);
            } 
        }
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}

int main() {
    Stack S;
    init(&S);
    int i;

    printf("\n");
    recursive_dir("/etc/", "conf", &S);
    printf("\n------------------------------\n");

    int top = S.top;
    struct dirent* entry;
    for (i=0; i<top; i++)
    {
        //struct dirent* entry = (struct dirent*)pop(&S);
        entry = (struct dirent*)S.value[i];

        printf("%p\n", entry);
        printf("%s [%x]\n", entry->d_name, entry->d_ino); 
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

What this outputs are the pointer values to the *dirent* structures, the file name that is within that structure, and the file serial number.   It then tries to cast the pointer to that *direct* to a (void*) and store it in a makeshift stack.

Later, I try to iterate over the values in the stack (well the array), cast it back to a *dirent* and then display the same information.

This works sometimes and doesn't work other times.  A trimmed output example:

```
...
0x7ff831806360
httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf [2cb6e07]
0x7ff831806398
httpd-ssl.conf [2cb6e08]
0x7ff8318063c0
httpd-userdir.conf [2cb6e09]
0x7ff8318063ec
httpd-vhosts.conf [2cb6e0a]
0x7ff831805250
httpd.conf [2cb6e0b]
0x7ff831805274
httpd.conf~previous [187a3]
0x7ff831807230
httpd-autoindex.conf [2cb6e10]
0x7ff831807260
httpd-dav.conf [2cb6e11]
0x7ff831807288
httpd-default.conf [2cb6e12]
0x7ff8318072b4
httpd-info.conf [2cb6e13]
...
--------------------------
...
0x7ff831807360
httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf [2cb6e17]
0x7ff831807398
httpd-ssl.conf [2cb6e18]
0x7ff8318073c0
httpd-userdir.conf [2cb6e19]
0x7ff8318073ec
httpd-vhosts.conf [2cb6e1a]
0x7ff831806250
 [0]
0x7ff831806230
320.whatis [2cb6ff6]
0x7ff8318042bc
asl.conf [2cb7d07]
0x7ff83180437c
autofs.conf [2cb6f5f]
0x7ff831805250
 [0]
0x7ff831805274
??$ [61666564]
0x7ff8318052e0
_response [6e7261]
...
```

Sometimes everything seems correct, and other times the file handle and / or the name are completely wacked out.

Generally when I see something like that it is because I am not doing something with memory correctly - having lived in the garbage collection world for so long I wouldn't be surprised that was it, but I am not sure why or how.

Any help would be appreciated.

(I've been coding for quite a number of year, I've just been out of the C arena for quite a while.  Please go easy on me.)

Comment: *"I studied C a long time ago, and I am recently trying to get back into it for fun"* - there are many things that are much more fun than programming in C.

Comment: @LihO True, but you can only eat and drink so much.

Comment: If you know that you are going to store pointers to `struct dirent`, why did you declare it as `void* value[Q_STACK_MAX];` then? I mean why `void*`?

Comment: The pointer returned by `readdir` may be statically allocated, and the contents overwritten by subsequent calls to `readdir`. Could be that. What happens if you copy the data before pushing it on the stack?

Comment: @LihO in the end it wont just be struct dirent, this is just a simplified example

Comment: @DanielFischer that was totally it.  Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 5):

The `dirent` structure returned by `readdir()` can reuse memory on repeated calls. If you want to save them, you should either copy them into dynamic objects, or allocate the objects first and call `readdir_r()`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Barmar it works perfectly after a malloc and memcpy.  I see where my error was.